# Weblogic gracefull shutdown still accepting new connections

Tags: weblogic

My Requirement is to gracefully shutdown weblogic server but the problem is it still accepting new connections and never shutdown gracefully as new connections coming from Load Balance. i propose solution to immediately drop all HTTP connections while gracefully shutting down but my supervisor is not convinced with that. also facing issue with session replication seems like application is not supporting session replication. please help

Comment: Gracefull shutdown means that the server will wait for current http sessions and transactions to end before it stops. Users who already have a http session on the server will be able to continue to send request, others will be rejected, the load balancer is then responsible to redirect these users to another server instance

Comment: yeah this should be expected behavior but this is not happening, the server shutting down gracefully still receiving new request and we can see in access logs that new requests are coming, application session count also do increased, test this with Jmeter  as well, server accepting new requests.

Comment: What is your weblogic version ? Does your application require authentication ?

Comment: weblogic version is 10.3.6 and yes authentication is kerberos SSO

Comment: Is this using an external load balancer like a F5? Is your load balancer using TCP based health checks?

Comment: We are using HA Proxy, but test that with proxy servlet LB as well. same problem